# Angular4 - clean code, how to don't duplicate code

Tags: angular

my questions is about good practice to write clean code in angular 4.

I have two components - client and host, their are pretty similar, both have some `<video>` element and both have similar code for handle this `<video>` element.

So what is the best way to implement this without duplicating code in this two components?

Remember if I will create another component for example video-component and then I will have in this `<video>` I must supply some public functions to turn on, off camera, microphone, start stream, close stream, etc... 
There are a few functions that I have to run from Client/Host-Component in my new Video-Component.

Comment: If you are using typescript, you can create a base class and two derived classes.

Comment: this is a really general question. but if you have a component that is more or less used in multiple places, like a video player with enhanced functionality, then you should create a component that wraps it so that it can be reused and customized with general inputs (like the source url) and that broadcasts general output events for consumers to handle (like video paused or something). You can also expose functions on it that consumers can use, either directly or through a shared service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reusing code in Angular is done via **services**. You can **inject** the services in other component by listing it in the component's constructor.

Angular will look through the provider tree and inject an instance of the service for you. Depending on whether you want a singleton service or a separate instance of the service for each component instance, you provide a service in the module or in the component.

The code in the component should be very lean and contain only very trivial functions and some state variables (although, even state is prefered to be substituted with observables, but that's another topic).

This model favors composition over inheritence and works much better, at least in a prototype based language such as JavaScript (and TypeScript). It allows you to compose functionality from multiple services instead of just a single base class.

Answer (score 2):

Angular is all about granularity. You should create something like "common frame" for your application where you will include **common components** and **services** for entire application. Common components are called **Nested components**.
**Examples:** **video player,** voting stars etc. After you specyfi all common nested components and services you just resolving them via builded in Angular Dependency Injection container to use them whenever you want. ( Just like **@Lazar Ljubenović** wrote).

Second type of the components are so called **Routable components** you are useing them when you want to have a significant part of a application. 
For **example:** welcome page, details page etc.

Besides that what you should check in the first place is [Angular2 style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide). You can find there very important informations about good practices.